# Uniform boundedness of integral points for Mordell's equation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $d$ be a non-zero integer. The equation

$$\displaystyle y^2 = x^3 - d$$

is known as Mordell's equation. It is closely related to the "discriminant equation" for elliptic curves, in the sense that if

$$\displaystyle y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$$

is an elliptic curve given in Weierstrass form, then its discriminant is given by $-16(4A^3 + 27B^2)$. Thus an integer $D$ is the discriminant of some elliptic curve (in Weierstrass form) if and only if

$$\displaystyle 4A^3 + 27B^2 = -16D$$

has integer solutions, and upon rearranging we see that this is similar to Mordell's equation.

It is known that quite often Mordell's equation has at most two solutions. Indeed, there is the following theorem:

Let $d$ be a positive, square-free integer. Suppose that $d$ can be written as $3t^2 \pm 1$ or $3t^2 \pm 8$ for some integer $t$ and the class number of the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ is not divisible by 3. Then the Mordell equation $y^2 = x^3 - d$ has at most four solutions. In fact the only case where there are four solutions is when $d = 11$; all other cases as above give at most two solutions.

This suggests that there should be a *uniform bound* for the number of solutions. Indeed, such a uniform bound is implied by a [theorem of Silverman](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01389220) and the absolute boundedness of the (rational) Mordell-Weil rank of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$. However, the opposite implication does not hold: a uniform bound on the number of integer points on elliptic curves with Weierstrass equation need not imply that the Mordell-Weil rank is absolutely bounded.

The best result I know of is due to [M. Bhargava, A. Shankar, T. Taniguchi, F. Thorne, J. Tsimerman, and Y. Zhao](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02458). Applying their Theorem 1.2 to this case gives that the number of integral solutions to $y^2 = x^3 - d$ is at most $O_{\varepsilon}\left(|d|^{0.334 + \varepsilon}\right)$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. This of course is far from the expectation... which I believe is a bound of the quality $O_{\varepsilon}\left(|d|^\varepsilon\right)$.

Is there an expectation for the number integer points on Mordell curves to be uniformly bounded? If so, what is the conjectured value for the uniform bound?

Comment: Of course the conjectured almost-uniform bound is $O_{\epsilon}(|d|^{\epsilon})$, because surely the $2$-part of the class group of a cubic field ought to be bounded by the $\epsilon$-th power of the full class number. This does hold in the special case that $E[2]$ is rational. You shouldn't be expecting a completely uniform bound on the number of integral points, unless you happen to believe in boundedness of ranks of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ (in which case, Silverman's result you cited gives this implication).

Comment: See  Abramovich, Dan Uniformity of stably integral points on elliptic curves. Invent. Math. 127 (1997), no. 2, 307–317, for a result assuming the Lang-Vojta conjectures.